# How to authenticate Ansible with Hashicorp Vault Signed SSH Certificates using "Valid_Principals"?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ssh-keys, hashicorp-vault

- I implemented Vault according to the documentation like this . https://medium.com/hashicorp-engineering/scaling-ssh-access-with-hashicorp-vault-720bde42a79d
- I follow this documentation to create playbook.https://github.com/nehrman/hc_vault_machine_credential
  And on the playbook I want to add the value "valid_principals" to authenticate. For example: valid_principals=it-system
- I tried many ways to add to the playbook but it didn't work.
- Please help me on the solution to this problem.
- Thank you.
- Here is my playbook look like:

```
- name: Create temporary directory to store public key
  tempfile:
   state: directory
   suffix: app
  register: r_tempfile
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: no
  run_once: true
  no_log: true

- name: Generate public key for sign to vault
  command:
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -f {{ r_tempfile.path | quote }}/id_rsa  -C "" -N ""
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: no
  run_once: true
  no_log: true

- name: Read public key
  set_fact:
   temp_public_key: "{{ lookup('file', r_tempfile.path + '/id_rsa.pub') }} "
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
  no_log: true

- name: Sign public key to Vault SSH CA
  uri:
   url: "{{ VAULT_SERVER }}/v1/ssh-ca-client-signer/sign/it-system-role"
   validate_certs: no
   method: POST
   headers:
    X-Vault-Token: "{{ VAULT_TOKEN }}"
   body: "{{ lookup('template', '{{ role_path }}/templates/vault_pubkey.j2') }}"
   body_format: json
   return_content: yes
  register: r_sign
  become: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true

- name: Store signed key temporarily
  copy:
   content: "{{ r_sign.json.data.signed_key }}"
   dest: "{{ r_tempfile.path }}/signed"
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: no
  run_once: true
  no_log: true
```

Comment: Please edit your question and give a precise definition of "it didn't work".  See [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.